# Adding nodes to cluster using initial tokens

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to add 2 new nodes to my cassandra cluster currently consisting of 9 nodes with initial tokens. Is there any specific way to determine where the node should be added?
  I have read some blogs which says you can add it at the end, but wont there be bloating of data in nodes while rearranging the tokens if they are added at the end.

This was my previous token ranges and the last column indicates the token range difference.
[Before adding nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HERvk.png)

If I add my 2 new nodes at the end as follows:

[After adding 2 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ6Mg.png)

I see there will data bloat(at node 7) when there are token moves.

Comment: your cluster use single token or vnodes?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: And how did you generate the tokens for your existing nodes?

Comment: I am using cassandra version 2.0.17 with single token. I have used token-generator for my earlier nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make token calculations yourself but take help from a token generator.

You should follow this chapter for adding a node: https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddRplSingleTokenNodes.html

You can use the following website to generate tokens (or use token-generator in version 2.2 or earlier): https://www.geroba.com/cassandra/cassandra-token-calculator/